# IntelliJ Jetty plugin does not extract war

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, jetty-9

I'm using IJ Ultimate 2020.3 and trying to set up a Jetty Server run configuration.

AFAIK, in order to start Jetty with a war artifact it is needed to be located in $JETTY_HOME/webapps directory.

But, it looks like the Jetty plugin of my IJ refuses to copy the war (exploded, or any other) artifact to that directory, which lead the Jetty server to fail.

I was able to start the Jetty server (from IJ) only after manually copying the war file into the webapps directory, so looks like the only problem is the 'copy' step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't copy the artifact into webapps, instead it instructs Jetty to load the artifact directly from the location that you have configured as the artifact output directory.

Artifact used for deployment:

[image: artifact]

Artifact output directory:

[image: output directory]

Startup logs showing that artifact is loaded directory from its output directory and not from webapps:

[image: logs]

Comment: please see my answer that include screenshots of my configuration and results

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CrazyCoder, this is a progress for me.
problem is that my output console suggests that it does not search for the artifact in the location it is set:
[image: artifact config]

[image: console output]

Comment: What do you have in the Run configuration Deployment tab?

Comment: I got the same configuration that you are using. it looks like there is some kind of collision with another tool that I'm using in order to allow local debugging while connecting to a k8s cluster (we use telepresence). From what I currently see, it looks like once the telepresence instance is closed the server starts and crashed up until the point it needs those other dependencies which comes from the cluster.

Comment: So, there were some developments. I've published them in a different thread and didn't want this one to be left like that. so if you would like to follow up you can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706187/telepresence-blocks-intellij-from-deploying-artifacts-to-jetty